# Use PyQGIS to export PDF ATLAS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, atlas

I have written a plugin in QGIS 3.16.0, and the result of the process is a project with atlas configured. The project is opened in the end with success, but the last step is to export the configured atlas inside him, I would like to export this atlas through PyQgis.

the last command before export atlas is

```
#Open the project, load the layers and atlas configured. 
project = QgsProject.instance()
        project.read(os.path.expanduser('~/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/polo/Map_and_Atlas.qgz'))
        print(project.fileName())

#Export configured Atlas inside project
?????
```

I need help in this last part, I tried various commands in my search, but no successes.
The output must be a PDF file for each line of coverage layer of ATLAS

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the following

```
from qgis import processing

coverage_layer = iface.activeLayer() # Change the ref for your own
# Clear layer filter
coverage_layer.setSubsetString("")
# Store id of each feature
coverageIds = [feature['area_n'] for feature in coverage_layer.getFeatures()]

for id in coverageIds:
    # Set layer filter so not need to play on the atlas filter
    coverage_layer.setSubsetString("area_n = '{}'".format(id))
    parameters = {
       "COVERAGE_LAYER" : coverage_layer,
       "DISABLE_TILED" : False,
       "DPI" : None,
       "FILTER_EXPRESSION" : "",
       "FORCE_VECTOR" : False,
       "GEOREFERENCE" : True,
       "INCLUDE_METADATA" : True,
       "LAYERS" : None,
       "LAYOUT" : "your_own_report_name", # Need your own layout name
       "OUTPUT" : "/tmp/atlas_{}.pdf".format(id), # Need to change part of path "/tmp/atlas_"
       "SIMPLIFY" : True,
       "SORTBY_EXPRESSION" : "",
       "SORTBY_REVERSE" : False,
       "TEXT_FORMAT" : 0
    }
    out = processing.run("native:atlaslayouttopdf", parameters)
    print(out['OUTPUT'])

# Clear layer filter
coverage_layer.setSubsetString("")
```

Comment: this is not works, I try use this comand lines and not works

Comment: This works. Tested before I answered. After, if you don't know to adapt to your context, I can't help more.

Comment: The result of the comand lines is a PDF for each line in coverage layer, or single PDF file with various page?

Comment: A single PDF for each line in coverage layer. So, it writes multiple PDFs

Comment: Please you can mark where in the code i insert the variables? The name of my coverage layer is Priority Areas, inside him have a column called 'area_n' (name of each map of atlas) and the information in the lines is AREA-01 AREA-02 AREA-03.

Comment: Sorry about aditional explanetion, i'm beginner in the comand lines

Comment: Make a fix on my side and adapted code to match your column name `area_n`

Comment: when you said "# Change the ref for your own" mean   coverage_layer = os.path.expanduser('~/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/polo/Process/Áreas Prioritárias.gpkg') right?

Comment: No, the one in your created project `Map_and_Atlas.qgz`. Normally, your project with atlas configured should already contains the coverage layer. `coverage_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('my layer name')` where `my layer name` is the coverage layer name

Comment: the line code looked like this >> coverage_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Priority Areas') Priority Areas is the coverage layer in the Atlas

Comment: in [coverage_layer.setSubsetString("")] i leave ("") blank ? or i need isert something

Comment: You leave blank